# Get all raws with the same minimum values in column from SQLite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I'am working with SQLite database in c#, using System.Data.SQLite, but this question is more about SQLite. I have a table like this:

```
    Date           Maxt           Mint           Snowrain
1956-04-19         13            -28              0.2
1996-04-19         16            -25              0.7
2015-04-19         12            -23.1             0
1958-04-19         16            -28               4
```

Using this query:

```
"SELECT strftime('%Y', Date), snowrain, min(mint) FROM Temps where Date like '%04-19'";
```

I get:

```
1956  0.2  -28
```

But i need to get all dates with minimum temperature, like:

```
1956  0.2  -28
1958   4   -28
```

What query i need to use?

P.S. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Why `-28` when you have rows with temperature lower than that? Or do you just want the rows where the temp is `-28`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the following will do what you want. However, the result of your original query should be `1996 0.7 -30` (I suspect that is because of the type affinity)

```
SELECT 
    strftime('%Y', Date), 
    snowrain, 
    mint 
FROM Temps 
WHERE Date 
    LIKE '%04-19' 
    AND CAST(mint AS REAL) = (
        SELECT min(CAST(mint AS REAL)) 
        FROM Temps 
        WHERE date LIKE '%04-19'
    );
```

- Note the CASTs to REAL, which may be why you are getting -28 instead of -30

Using the following to test :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Temps;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Temps (Date TEXT, Maxt, Mint, Snowrain);
INSERT INTO Temps VALUES 
    ('1956-04-19',13,'-28',0.2),
    ('1996-04-19',16,'-30',0.27),
    ('2015-04-19',12,'-29.1',0),
    ('1958-04-19',16,'-28',4),
    ('1997-04-19',16,'-30',0.27) /* ADDED as -30 min temp  so multiple lowest tempts are available*/
;

SELECT 
    strftime('%Y', Date), 
    snowrain, 
    mint 
FROM Temps 
WHERE Date 
    LIKE '%04-19' 
    AND CAST(mint AS REAL) = (
        SELECT min(CAST(mint AS REAL)) 
        FROM Temps 
        WHERE date LIKE '%04-19'
    );
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Temps /* Clean up testing environment */ ;
```

- **Note** the above uses data for the **Mint** column that will, if not using the CASTs return -28.

results in :-

[image]

- The highlighted row being the extra row added to show that all rows with the minimum temperaure are retrieved.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I made a mistake typing a table. I edited my table in question... Thank you so much. It works.

Comment: @Сиволапый No problem the above should work irrespective.

Answer (score 1):

If using sqlite 3.25 or newer, the `rank()` window function can be used:

```sql
WITH ranked AS
 (SELECT date, snowrain, mint, rank() OVER (ORDER BY mint) AS rnk
  FROM temps
  WHERE date LIKE '%-04-19')
SELECT strftime('%Y', date) AS year, snowrain, mint
FROM ranked
WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY year;
```

```
year        snowrain    mint      
----------  ----------  ----------
1956        0.2         -28       
1958        4           -28
```

[db<>fiddle demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=1e7b30b14cf6c91ed11ef215b0d1b8de)

Comment: There are many values in my table. Table in my question is just for example. I think that's why your answer return wrong value. But anyway, thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @Сиволапый It returns exactly the expected rows from your sample data.

Comment: Yes, if using ascending.

Comment: @Сиволапый Ah, I see you changed your data from when I copied it.